# BGP status UP/DOWN counter SNMP Monitoring

Tags: snmp

I have cisco 6509 for BGP with upstream providers, also have SNMP Monitoring server Solarwinds in my network.

I need to monitor BGP Up/Down counter, like if BGP status Up/Down timer is less then or equal to 5 Minutes SNMP server trigger an alert

Like in below, one of my peer was down and restored after an intermittent flap, interfaces are already in monitoring but due to high CPU during route receiving/learning SNMP goes timeout.

Neighbor V       AS MsgRcvd MsgSent   TblVer  InQ OutQ **Up/Down**  State/PfxRcd

2.2.2.1  4       22222 2129685 2077555   107685    0    0 ***3w5d***            0

3.3.3.1  4       33333 12052862  229372   107685    0    0 **00:11:45**     3045

So, let router do what he is doing at time of flap, i need my SNMP server to send alert when he get BGP UP/DOWN timer <=5,  and i am unable to find OID for this attribute.

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try two approaches, both based on CISCO-BGP4-MIB:

1. If your Solarwinds server can receive snmp traps and alert on them, than configure router to send snmp notifications (snmp traps) to Solarwind server on BGP state changes. For bgp monitoring these traps may work for you: cbgpFsmStateChange, cbgpBackwardTransition, cbgpPeer2EstablishedNotification, cbgpPeer2BackwardTransNotification, cbgpPeer2FsmStateChange, cbgpPeer2BackwardTransition (see detailed description in MIB, supported traps may depend on IOS version on router).
2. Configure Solarwinds to do snmp poll of OIDs from CISCO-BGP4-MIB::cbgpPeer2Table, in particular, cbgpPeer2State, cbgpPeer2PrevState,cbgpPeer2FsmEstablishedTransitions, cbgpPeer2FsmEstablishedTime and alert appropriately.

Similar OIDs for polling and traps for notifications can also be found in BGP4-MIB.